# EF Core In-Memory Database Not Saving To DbSet

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, integration-testing

## Overview

I am currently unit/integration testing my repository pattern with the in-memory database EF Core provides. I am on version 6.0.1 for the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory nuget and using Visual Studio 2022. I am running into issues saving data to the database. Below I have included snippets of my code.

### My data model:

```
public class Example : IExample

public Guid Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
```

### My base repository class:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class

private readonly DbSet<T> _dbSet;
private readonly DbContext _db;

public Repository(DbContext db)
{
    _dbSet = db.Set<T>();
    _db = db;
}

public virtual async Task Add(T entity)
{
    await _dbSet.AddAsync(entity);
}

public virtual async Task<int> SaveAsync(CancellationToken token = default)
{
    return await _db.SaveChangesAsync(token);
}
```

### My repository class:

```
public class ExampleRepo : Repository<Example>

public ExampleRepo(ExampleContext db) : base(db)
{
}
```

### My DbContext Class

I can show my IEntityConfiguration class for the **ExampleBuilder** shown below if it is needed but I don't believe that to be the problem.

```
public class ExampleContext : DbContext

private readonly IHttpContextAccessor? _httpContextAccessor;

public ExampleContext(DbContextOptions<ExampleContext> options) : base(options)
{
    if (options == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));
}

public ExampleContext(DbContextOptions<ExampleContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) 
    : base(options)
{
    if (options == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContextAccessor));
}

public DbSet<Example>? Examples { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ExampleBuilder));
    if (assembly is null)
    {
        throw new DataException("Could not find the assembly containing the designated model builder");
    }

    builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(assembly);

    foreach (var entity in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        entity.SetSchema("dbo");
    }
}

public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken token = default)
{
    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries()
                                       .Where(x => x.State is EntityState.Added or EntityState.Modified or EntityState.Deleted))
    {
        var user = _httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.Name ?? "User";
        entry.Property("ModifiedBy").CurrentValue = user;

        if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            entry.Property("CreatedBy").CurrentValue = user;
        }

        if (entry.State != EntityState.Deleted) continue;

        entry.State                              = EntityState.Modified;
        entry.Property("IsActive").CurrentValue = false;
    }

    return base.SaveChangesAsync(token);
}
```

### My DbContext factory method:

```
private ExampleContext GenerateDbContext()
{
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ExampleContext>()
                  .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                  .Options;

    return new ExampleContext(options);
}
```

### My unit/integration test utilizing xUnit and NET6.0

```
[Fact]
public async Task GetAllEntities_ShouldReturnEntities_WhenEntitiesExist()
{
    // Arrange

    // I used Bogus nuget for single source for generating valid models
    var entity = ExampleFaker.GetModelFaker()
                             .Generate();

    await using var context = GenerateDbContext();
    var             repo    = new ExampleRepo(context);

    await repo.Add(entity);
    var changes = await repo.SaveAsync();

    // Act

    // Consulted this link already. Bottom answer is most related
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184937/dbcontext-not-returning-local-objects
    var response = await repo.GetAll();

    // Assess
    TestOutputHelper.WriteLine($"Added entity to repository: {entity.ToJson()}");
    TestOutputHelper.WriteLine("Expected entities saved: 1");
    TestOutputHelper.WriteLine($"Actual entities saved: {changes}");
    TestOutputHelper.WriteLine($"Response: {response?.ToJson()}");

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(1, changes);
    Assert.NotNull(response);
    Assert.NotEmpty(response);
    Assert.IsType<List<Example>>(response.ToList());
}
```

### Analysis & Issue

The **changes** variable returns 1 so I interpret this as EF does not have any issue with my model as well as I would think it successfully saved my model in the in-memory database. However, during my **GetAll** retrieval, no data is returned. When I debug and look into the repository private members, it shows the **DbSet** is empty so it is not the **GetAll** method causing the issue either. Since this is also just within the scope of the unit test, I don't think my Program.cs configuration has anything to do with the issue I am seeing. I have been looking at this for quite a while and can't figure out the small detail I am probably missing for the life of me.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Probably not the cause, but using in-memory is not recommended https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/#approach-3-the-ef-core-in-memory-database.

Comment: I believe the second to last paragraph states it is acceptable for this scenario. I am using an actual database for production but for unit and end to end tests, I am using in memory databases

Comment: Have you tried setting the same InMemoryDatabaseRoot on the UseInMemoryDatabase(...) call ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193986/multiple-in-memory-databases-with-the-same-name